# MySQL query four years ago

Tags: php, mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I happen to have ordered some data for years, I have a column over the years since the dates are not updated in the records. How could inquire to get me records only four years ago?

I tried this way:

```
$year=date ("Y"); //get the current year


$cons="SELECT     iden,
                  ano,
                  wh,
                  so
                  FROM content WHERE wh='n'
                  AND ano BETWEEN 2013 AND".$year ." 
                  ORDER BY ano desc, id DESC";
```

But the problem is that next year I have to modify the query to put 2014 instead of 2013. Had way to mount a conditional subtraction do?

Ano column I have: 2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, etc.

Let's see if I can lend a hand, because I have little knowledge of SQL and would like to learn more. Thank you.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  And sample data and desired results would help explain what you are doing.

Comment: sorry, I edited, it is mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not just subtract 4 from your current year and use that as the first year?

```
$previous_year=date("Y")-4; 

"...BETWEEN ".$previous_year." and ".$year."...."
```

Comment: YEAHHHHHHHHH, now I feel silly for not having happened, it's great, thank you very much !!

Comment: Until last five minutes will not let me give valid answer, back in five minutes. Thank you. : P